# Compare given size with required size and show mismatch

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm currently having a bit of trouble with my current project. I have two arrays - the first array contains reference values for disk size:

```
$RequiredDisks0 = New-Object System.Object
$RequiredDisks0 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "DeviceID" -Value "C:"
$RequiredDisks0 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "SizeGB" -Value "80"
```

The second array contains the disk information of the underlying system:

```
$SystemDisks = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk |
               Where {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
               select DeviceID,
                 @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f ($_.Size/1gb))}}
```

What I would like to do, is check the given array against the reference array to see if any given disks are smaller than required. I've found out that I can compare the arrays by using

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $RequiredDisks -DifferenceObject $SystemDisks -Property SizeGB,DeviceID
```

And I indeed receive the differences as follows:

```
SizeGB DeviceID SideIndicator
------ -------- -------------
    99 C:       =>           
    15 H:       =>           
   100 I:       =>           
    80 C:       <=           
    25 H:       <=           
   200 I:       <=
```

Where I'm having trouble is working with the output. The result I'd like to achieve is an output stating "Disk n is smaller than required!". I know that everything with the side indicator "<=" is the required value and everything with the "=>" side indicator is the given value. I've tried a `foreach` statement but I am unable to process the data as needed - I need to check the given value against the required value and if it's smaller, tell me so. How can I again compare these values as required? Basically a "foreach object where SideIndicator is <= compare to object where SideIndicator is => and DeviceID equals DeviceID". How do I translate that into proper code?

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question. If you found a solution yourself: post it as an answer of your own. If you're looking to improve your code: post a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the wink - wilco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the `Compare-Object` is doing a double comparison on both properties. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) or another StackOverflow soul may be able to help with that command.

My approach would be to translate your pseudo-code into code:

```
foreach ($disk in $SystemDisks){

   $ref = $RequiredDisks | Where-object {$_.DeviceID -eq $disk.DeviceID}

   if([int]($disk.SizeGB) -lt [int]($ref.SizeGB){
       Write-Output "Disk $($disk.DeviceID) is smaller than required!"
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar solution myself, but will try a run with this version. Looks a lot nicer than my double foreach XD I'll post my results tomorrow!

Comment: Solution works fine and is definitely nicer, than what I came up with. Marking as answer! Thank you very much :-)